# Initializing words of a sentence stored in a string into UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

I am trying to initialise the words of a sentence into UIlabels in the order of the word of the sentence every time I click on a UIbutton.

I also want to recognise when the sentence in the different labels is approaching the end of the screen, which then takes the next word and puts it in the line below the words of the sentence like pressing Enter in Microsoft Word.

I have tried this code but it loads all the words on the same spot.

```
- (void)change:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *sentence = @"i am a boy with passion";
    NSArray *array = [sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]];

    CGFloat xVal = 11.0;

    for (NSString *words in array) {
        UILabel *labelText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, 50, 300, 80)];

        labelText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        labelText.layer.borderWidth = 6.0;
        labelText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        labelText.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f];
        labelText.text = words;
        xVal=+200;
        [self.view addSubview:labelText];
        [labelText setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
         [labelText sizeToFit];
```

Comment: "Also, i want Xcode to recognise when the sentence in the different labels is approaching the end of the screen" - good luck with that, Xcode doesn't do stuff like this. Maybe you want **your app** to do that instead?

Comment: @H2CO3 oh wow.. thanks for the heads up, what if i create transparent labels by myself and write a code to put the words in this labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xVal=+200;` means xVal=200. So except first label all others got same *origin*. Thats why they got over lapped.

For finding whether the label moved out of bounds
Initialise `yVal` outside for loop,

Inside the loop add

> ```
>    CGFloat width = [words sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]].width;
>     if (self.view.frame.size.width<xVal+width) {
>         yVal+=50;
>         xVal = 11;
>     }
>     UILabel *labelText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 300, 80)];
> ```

Make sure to use, a)the font you would be using for label in finding the width, b) adjust increment in `yVal` according to yor need.

Dont forget to change `xVal=+200;` to `xVal+=200;`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
xVal=+200;
```

This is the same as saying `xVal = 200`; the plus sign means positive 200 rather than 200 more.  Try this instead:

```
xVal += 200;
```